# built-in Android sharing module, the Facebook Android application

Tags: android

It is possible to share to facebook using share intent. When you click on a send button, a list of default application set up on the device is shown in a pop up dialog. My question is is it possible to share to only one application using share intent. For example using share intent to send to facebook only. The share intent open the native facebook application directly.

I found this link: http://vnstep.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/share-via-android/

but

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "anc");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ccc");
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
        if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            shareIntent.setComponent(name);
            context.startActivity(shareIntent);
            break;
        }
    }
```

getting error log

```
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fb.app/fb.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2182)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2207)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at fb.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2136)
07-19 21:26:30.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not filter any application from share intent. If you still want to do that then use Facebook SDK.

Comment: but the sdk does not provide the inbuilt android sharing module popup for Facebook ?

Comment: But you can implement that.

Comment: how please provide me a tutorial anything to start

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: Your need is only to share content to facebook?

Comment: yes a link but i need to get the features of inbuilt facebook share intent of android